# Spring Boot Hibernate Properties are not picking up from properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

After upgrading spring boot version to 1.4.2.RELEASE from 1.3, project is not able to pick up the export.sql file in classpath.

In my properties(.yml) file I have 2 data sources(serviceapione, serviceapitwo) like below.

spring 1.3 properties

`spring:
  config:
    location: classpath:.
serviceapione:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:app_db;Mode=Oracle;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password:
    testWhileIdle: true
    validationQuery: SELECT sysdate FROM dual
    maxWait: 1000
    maxActive: 20
    maxIdle: 9
    minIdle: 2
    testOnBorrow: false
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    database: H2
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    generate-ddl: true`

Same way the serviceapitwo and this is loaded from DataSourceConfig class

```
@Configuration
public class ServiceApiOneDataSourceConfig {

  @Bean
  @Primary
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "serviceapione.datasource")
  public DataSource serviceDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder
        .create()
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public EntityManagerFactory serviceEntityManagerFactory() {
     HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new      HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();

     LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new   LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
     factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
     factory.setPackagesToScan("package.path");
     factory.setDataSource(serviceDataSource());
     factory.afterPropertiesSet();
     return factory.getObject();
 }
}
```

After migration I'm having below versions,
spring-boot: 1.4.2.RELEASE
hibernate: 5.0.11.FINAL

> So to make the service up and running without any issues I have to add the below configuration in .yml file
>   and add the hibernate properties(ex: hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto) from config class.

`spring:
  config:
    location: classpath:.
  jpa:
    open-in-view: false`

DataSource class

```
@Bean
public EntityManagerFactory commerceEntityManagerFactory() {
  HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();

  LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new   LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
  factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
  factory.setPackagesToScan("package.path");
  factory.setDataSource(serviceDataSource());
  Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
  properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
  factory.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
  factory.afterPropertiesSet();
  return factory.getObject();
}
```

> But I don't want to define these hibernate properties in config class. How can I
>   load it from the properties file directly to the context.

I tried adding,

`config:
    location: classpath:.
  jpa:
    open-in-view: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create`

and tried by adding the hibernate properties to datasource part also,

`serviceapione:
  datasource:
    //properties
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    database: H2
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    generate-ddl: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create`